# Short name of the file path on Windows is not correctly returned

Tags: java, windows, filesystems, jna

I want to get short file path from a given Windows path.
For this reason I use the following JAVA code (with JNA library):

```
    char[] result = new char[65535];
    Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetShortPathName(file.toString(), result, result.length);
    System.out.println(Native.toString(result));
```

The above code works fine. However, in some cases the returned value is empty string. For example, using the following existing path on Windows yeilds an empty value:

C:\Users\someuser\Downloads\Gfl4AHIHf6SVMPMT9hjitNZOSXVofG1A9VJrv66YerqDfW8TW73O3VUb1wYYnOOB2l9CvSmTjfPLUvIwwvkddiL3sj7XNB1gqGGrUnmotsG4V3WR50SV1JAkXe2M0MpR4VDoYAUt5WgLpdLqoIdRlH4bd7OcZ3j0GOs90FGuZpZpjhEZBobNz1CwK50jJWYCwAHNmaYOYrC3JnOl6xtX4phNJm\Gfl4AHIHf6SVMPMT9hjitNZOSXVofG1A9VJrv66YerqDfW8TW73O3VUb1wYYnOOB2l9CvSmTjfPLUvIwwvkddiL3sj7XNB1gqGGrUnmotsG4V3WR50SV1JAkXe2M0MpR4VDoYAUt5WgLpdLqoIdRlH4bd7OcZ3j0GOs90FGuZpZpjhEZBobNz1CwK50jJWYCwAHNmaYOYrC3JnOl6xtX4phNJmdsMlll

The returned value of `Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetShortPathName` is ***0***, which according to javadoc is

> If the function fails for any other reason, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call *GetLastError*.

Calling *GetLastError* returns ***3***.

Now, using the following command:

```
dir /x
```

I'm able to see that the file actually has an alredy generated short name (GFL4AH~1).

What I've missed?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
 int returnCode = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetShortPathName("\\\\?\\" + file.toString(), result, result.length);
```

From MS docs:

> To specify an extended-length path, use the "\?\" prefix. For example, "\?\D:\very long path".